# How to list the files greater than specific timestamp in its pattern in Unix?

Tags: unix, ksh

Can you please how I can accomplish the below scenario in Unix Ksh command?

I have a job J1 which is completed by the time HH:MM.  I would like to list all the files created by this job J1,  The file has the timestamp in its pattern YYYYMMDDHHMMSS_?

where YYYYMMDD is the date, HHMMSS is the system timestamp.   I want to list the files if the job's timestamp is less than the file time stamp as the job creates the files, the timestamp of the job would be greater than the file timestamp?

Regards
Ben

Comment: Look to the `find` command and tests like `-anewer`, `-cnewer` and `-mmin` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: (Assuming the files listed)

```
$ ls -la
total 44K
drwxr-xr-x  2 gp         users 4.0K Oct 27 14:56 .
drwxr-xr-x 11 gp         users 4.0K Oct 27 14:57 ..
-rw-r--r--  1 gp         users    0 Oct 23 14:45 logfile
-rw-r--r--  1 gp         users  137 Oct 27 15:09 t2t2
prw-r--r--  1 gp         users    0 Oct 23 12:34 testpipe
-rw-r--r--  1 gp         users    0 Oct 23 14:51 tmpfile
-rw-r--r--  1 gp         users    7 Oct 27 14:58 ttt

# Find newer files
$ find . -newer ttt -print
./t2t2

# Find files that are NOT newer
$ find . ! -newer ttt -print
.
./tmpfile
./testpipe
./logfile
./ttt

# You can eliminate the directories (all of them) from the output this way:
$ find . ! -newer ttt ! -type d -print
./tmpfile
./testpipe
./logfile
./ttt
# or this way
$ find . ! -newer ttt -type f -print
```

Note that the different forms of the "newer" option (like anewer, cnewer) will not compare the other files against the the same timestamp. You might have to do a few tests to see which version suits you better.

If you must use the timestamp in the file name, and the different options of "find", including "mmin" are not acceptable, then you will have to examine the embedded timestamp of each file name. I suggest checking into these commands:

```
# You have to escape the < of > signs you use.
$ expr "fabc" \< "cde"
0
$ expr "abc" \< "cde"
1
```

and this:

```
FILENAME="ABC_20141026101112.log" ; TIMESTAMP="`expr \"$FILENAME\" : \".*_20\([0-9]\{12\}\).*$\"`";echo $TIMESTAMP
```

So a "while read" loop, looking at all the file names and comparing their timestamps using the above "expr" compares should do the job. Ideally, I'd try to see if "find" can do the job because reading and examining each file will be slower. If you have thousands of files in that directory, then I would try some other solution. If you are interested in more options, let me know.